# Como restringir os clientes que recebem as mensagens com socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Galera, como faço para ter esse controle no socket.io. Vou ilustrar minha situação: imagine que eu tenha um lista de amigos, como faço para que as minhas mensagens cheguem apenas para meus amigos e não para todos os clientes conectados, tipo uma rede social onde só quem pode ver minhas publicações são meus amigos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal neste cenário é utilizar o conceito de [rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Rooms) que o socket.io expõe. Basicamente você agrupa certos sockets, neste caso os dos seus amigos, em uma "sala", assim você pode enviar mensagens/eventos para esta room e todos nela vão receber. Uma leve complicação neste caso é que você é amigo de alguém e essa pessoa também é sua amiga, logo cada pessoa tem a sua própria room que contêm todos os seus respectivos amigos.

Um rascunho da ideia em código:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
var allSockets = {}; // todos os sockets conectados
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    allSockets[socket.id] = allSockets;

    // adiciona um amigo na sua sala de amigos e também adiciona você na sala de amigos deste amigo. As salas são representadas pela ID contida no socket da sua conexão ("socket.id")
    socket.on('adicionarAmigo', function(amigoSocketId) {
        socket.join(amigoSocketId); // você ("socket") entra na sala de amigos do seu novo amigo
        allSockets[amigoSocketId].join(socket.id); // seu amigo (o socket em allSockets[amigoSocketId]) entra na sua sala de amigos
    });

    socket.on('enviarParaAmigos', function(message) {
        // aqui você envia a mensagem para todos os sockets que estão na sala "socket.id", que é sala dos seus amigos
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('message', message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e o rascunho. Vou usa-lo e melhora-lo. Abs